# Problemas com SCROLLTOP

Tags: javascript, jquery, rolamento

Estou com problemas com `scroll-top`. A função implementada deveria pegar o `input` que estive-se com `focus` é leva-lo ao top com `scroll-top`, porém funciona de forma satisfatória apenas para os primeiros clicks na parte de cima da página, e quando vou descendo dando click ele comporta de forma não satisfatória ao invés de levar para o topo da página ele leva para o bottom da página. Observei que algumas vezes o valor do `position` é negativo, porém isto não é sempre.

Tratei de certificar que estive-se espaço para que o campo rolar para cima. Então o problema não está no espaço para rolagem.

Abaixo segue meu código:

```
var tamanho = screen.height - 108 - 80;
var inputs = $('input').get();

$(inputs).on('focus', function () {
  $(".ajusteTeclado").css("height", tamanho + "px");
  $(".ajusteTeclado").show();
  var pos = $(this).offset(),
      position = pos.top - 60;

 // positiohttp://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/108569/4995n = ((position < 0)? position * -1 : position);
  console.log(position);
  $(this).closest('.scrollPosition').scrollTop(position);
});
```

O que poderia ser ?

Preciso que toda vez que o campo tive-se em foco ele deveria localizar ao topo da página.

Comment: Já tentou usar `pos = $(this).position()` ao invés de `pos = $(this).offset()`?

Comment: Ja sim, na verdade conseguir resolver. Bastou adicionar o $(this).closest('.scrollPosition').scrollTop(position); no lugar de position = pos.top - 60; ficando assim position = $(this).closest('.scrollPosition').scrollTop(position) +  pos.top - 60;

Comment: Então coloca isso em uma resposta, para a gente saber com mais facilidade o que você fez.

Comment: Sim, estou so compilando projeto para ter certeza

Comment: Ok. Obrigado por contribuir para o conteúdo do site.

Answer (score 1):

Para resolver este problema temos que entender o principio dos objetos:

o comando `$(this).offset()` pega o position relacionado com o campo onde está o `focus`.

Se pegarmos apenas ele e em seguida executar o `scrolltop()` vemos que ele irá sim levar para o top, porém no primeiro click, onde toda a `div` e o campo estão zerados no sentidos de movimentação.

O problema acontece ai, é necessário pegar a posição atual do campo em relação a `div`, pois pode acontecer da `div` está muito acima do campo com `focus`, por isto o problema que as vezes informava valores negativos.

Então com estes aprendizado concluímos que devemos pegar a posição atual do campo com focus + a distancia que o campo está do top, e no meu caso retirar 60 px pois tenho uma borda. O código final ficou assim:

```
var tamanho = screen.height - 108 - 80;
var inputs = $('input, textarea').get();

$(inputs).on('focus', function () {
  $(".ajusteTeclado").css("height", tamanho + "px");
  $(".ajusteTeclado").show();
  var pos = $(this).offset(),
      position = $(this).closest('.scrollPosition').scrollTop() + pos.top - 60;

 // position = ((position < 0)? position * -1 : position);
  console.log(position);
  console.log("Offset " + pos.top);
  $(this).closest('.scrollPosition').scrollTop(position);
});
```

Observe que em `position` eu pego a distancia do campo na tela e faço o que expliquei logo acima.